# p-adic topology on finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory

Let's take $\mathbb{Q}_p \subset K$ a finite extension endowed with the $p$-adic topology.
For $z \in K$ is the application $x \to x+z $ continuous ?
Can a set can be open and not be $K$ ?
I actually want to show that given an open subgroup $I \subset O_K^{\times}$ the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ space its generate in $K$ his the entire $K$.
So first it is easy to show that $<I>$ is open but I don't know if I can conclude from here ?

Comment: Yes, yes${}{}$.

Comment: because I have the following assertion : If $I \subset O_K^{\times}$ is an open subgroup then the $\mathbb{Q_p}$ vector space generated by $I$ in $K$ is equal to $K$. So I wanted to show that $<I>$ is open and obtain $I=K$ wich by your answer is not necessarily true

Comment: any ideas @LordSharktheUnknown ?

Comment: How about putting the question you are actually interested in into the question?

Comment: I thought my question was minimal to answer my actual question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your group $I$ is open, it contains a neighbourhood of $1$ and
so a set of the form $1+\mathfrak{p}^n$ where $\mathfrak p$ is the maximal
ideal of the valuation ring of $K$. Then the $\Bbb Z$-linear
span of $I$ contains $\mathfrak{p}^n$ and so the $\Bbb Q$-linear
span contains $\Bbb Q\mathfrak{p}^n$ which equals $K$.

Comment: Why would it contain a set of this particular form ?

Comment: Because the sets $1+\mathfrak p^n$  are a neighborhood base at $1$ for the topology of the units, just as the sets $\mathfrak p^n$ are a neighborhood base at $0$ for the topology of $K$. (Uses the fact that you get a neighborhood base at any point by translating the given neighborhood base at the identity.)

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much that's clear now !

Comment: Just to be sure why do you have $\mathbb{Q}p^n=K$ ?